# ColdFusion 10/Windowns 7 Pro 64bit Connection verification failed for data source

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I’m having issue setting up a data source on my new windows 7 Pro 64bit laptop. I have a fresh install of Coldfusion 10 with latest hot fix and Microsoft SQL Express 2012 64bit.

I have ensured that TCP/IP enable and set TCP port to 1433 in the SQl server configuration manager. I've also tried removing the TCP Dynamic Ports.

I’m still getting this error:

> Connection verification failed for data source: TEST
>
> java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Login failed for user 'xxxxx'.
>
> The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Login failed for user 'xxxxx'.

I’m not sure what I’m missing at this point. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you enable mixed mode authentication in SQL server? IIRC, it defaults to Windows Authentication only http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332

Comment: That's what I was missing, thank you very much Leigh. Cheer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(From the comments...)*

Did you enable [mixed mode authentication](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332) in SQL server? IIRC, it defaults to Windows Authentication only.

**Instructions from link:**

> To ... configure SQL Server in Mixed Authentication
>   Mode ... [for] SQL Server 2014, SQL Server
>   2012, SQL Server 2008, and SQL Server 2005
>
> 1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
> 2. Right-click the server, and then click *Properties*.
> 3. On the Security page, under *Server authentication*, click the *SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode* option button, and then
>      click OK.
> 4. In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to restart SQL Server.