# Login failed for user 'sa' while trying to create datasource with Railo

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cfml, railo, lucee

So I'm trying to setup Railo and I want to add a datasource.
For the database I'm using Microsoft SQL server Management Studio.
But now I've run into the classical problem: "Login failed for user 'sa'. ClientConnectionId:afd80ac2-0744-4a7d-a9f7-083d93adee0d"

What I've done so far:

- With the SQL Server Configuration Manager in the TCP/IP settings I enabled the IPs I had to.
- I set the password for the user 'sa' in MSSQL and I added a user mapping for the table I want to use.
- I made the user 'sa' the owner of the DB i want to connect to
- Restarted the SQL service, my computer and Railo multiple times.

I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Comment: Is this related to "ColdFusion"?

Comment: Yes, since it's Railo (which is CF hosting) causing the error.

Comment: @max_eddy - I know what you mean, but the ["ColdFusion" tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/coldfusion/info) has shifted to refer to Adobe's ColdFusion application (specifically), rather than the cfml language in general.

Comment: Alright that's kinda weird seeing that the language's name is Coldfusion but I've edited it.

Comment: No, Max, the language is "CFML". The application server from Adobe is called "ColdFusion". The one from Railo is called "Railo". Both process CFML files.

Comment: you learn something everyday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Leigh mentioned in the comments to look at my logs it had the following message: "Login failed for user 'max'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'test'. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]"

I then tried to make a connection without mentioning a database and that worked.

Comment: Max, you should "accept" this answer to your own question so this no longer shows up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0):

I would also point to ***[Leigh's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433235/coldfusion-10-windowns-7-pro-64bit-connection-verification-failed-for-data-sourc)*** which explains how to turn Mixed-Mode authentication on, as this can also cause this error. Since the cause of this isn't on Railo/Lucee's end, this issue still arises in 2018.

I just don't want a useful answer to get lost to history, nor plagiarize an answer I barely found.